# Trying to get rid of localhost in outgoing email -- Sendmail

Tags: sendmail, localhost

I'm running sendmail and I've appeared on the CBL. I've already fixed a couple issues, but I can't figure out how to get rid of these last two localhost mentions. I commented out the localhost line in my /etc/hosts file and I made sure that there's a line in my sendmail.cf that reads:

```
Djmydomain.com
```

I'm going to keep looking for other things to do, but I'd really like my messages to not be flagged as spam because I'm a sendmail newbie. Thanks in advance!

Here are the message headers from an email I sent to my gmail account:

```
Delivered-To: me@gmail.com
Received: by 10.90.70.19 with SMTP id s19cs391179aga;
        Fri, 26 Feb 2010 17:18:08 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.142.196.20 with SMTP id t20mr692104wff.88.1267233488585;
        Fri, 26 Feb 2010 17:18:08 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <me@mydomain.com>
Received: from mydomain.com ([999.999.999.999])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTP id 36si1793616pxi.21.2010.02.26.17.18.07;
    Fri, 26 Feb 2010 17:18:08 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of me@mydomain.com designates 999.999.999.999 as permitted sender) client-ip=999.999.999.999;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of me@mydomain.com designates 999.999.999.999 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=me@mydomain.com
```

******This one*******

```
Received: from mydomain.com (ip6-localhost [127.0.0.1])
```

.

```
    by mydomain.com (8.14.2/8.14.2/Debian-2build1) with ESMTP id o1R1ICwB015625
for <me@gmail.com>; Fri, 26 Feb 2010 17:18:12 -0800
```

******And this one:******

```
Received: (from me@localhost)
```

.

```
    by mydomain.com (8.14.2/8.14.2/Submit) id o1R1IC5W015624
for me@gmail.com; Fri, 26 Feb 2010 17:18:12 -0800
Date: Fri, 26 Feb 2010 17:18:12 -0800
From: me <me@mydomain.com>
Message-Id: <201002270118.o1R1IC5W015624@mydomain.com>
To: me@gmail.com
Subject: test again

test
```

I just tried commenting out a few lines in /etc/hosts having to do with ipv6 and I got this:

```
Received: from mydomain.com (localhost [127.0.0.1] (may be forged))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to uninstall sendmail and install postfix.

For some reason, uninstalling sendmail does not stop the MTA, so run

```
ps aux | grep mail
```

and kill the process manually. Postfix works great right out of the box.

edit:

Also, to prevent local delivery (unless you actually deliver email from the server using pop etc), in main.cf just get rid of the domain name reference. Works like a charm.

Another benefit of Postfix: mailq command shows bounces and replies from server if they deny the message. I could never figure this out with sendmail, but with postfix the mailq is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

These look related to how you are connecting to sendmail (as in, opening a TCP/IP connection to it from the local machine). Do they look any different when you send mail through that sendmail instance from a different machine? If so, then your solution is to connect to the local machine differently when sending mail from itself.

J.Ja